# faster way to identify documents with duplicated fields in nestedt array of object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am searching the faster option to match documents with duplicated values in fields inside nested array , example document matching the criteria:

```
{
 "key": 2,
a: [
  {
    p: [
      {
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      },
      {
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
 }
```

I need to find faster way to match only the documents having duplicated a.p.id values , in the example document with key:2 is having a.p.id:3 duplicated , is this possible without using $uwind?

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nYNV1Ma5BfC)

Expected output:

```
{ key:2 , id:3 }
```

or the full matching document

what I have to the moment is this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qs7xuYQy-vQ

But I believe there is always something better ... , I am thinking maybe something with $reduce/$size operations or $push/$addToSet can be near the answer I am searching , but havent identified yet ...

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: If I do $unwind/$unwind/$group/$match I will find it , but with collection with documents > 100M it takes alot of time to identify 10% documents like: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qs7xuYQy-vQ

Comment: With `"a"` being an array of objects, if a `p.id` in one object matches a `p.id` in another object, is that considered a duplicate?

Comment: No , for this task I search only duplicates per document ... , but for the actual collection also not expected id duplications across the entire collection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

1. Flatten and clean the arrays to one array per `key`
2. Match only documents with duplications
3. Find an array of duplicated values
4. Format the response

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      cleanArr: {$reduce: {
          input: "$a",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.p.id"]}
      }},
      key: 1,
      _id: 0
  }},
  {$match: {
      $expr: {$gt: [
          {$size: "$cleanArr"},
          {$size: {$setIntersection: ["$cleanArr"]}}
      ]}
  }},
  {$project: {
      key: 1,
      res: {$reduce: {
          input: "$cleanArr",
          initialValue: {arr: [], id: []},
          in: {$cond: [
              {$in: ["$$this", "$$value.arr"]},
              {arr: "$$value.arr", id: {$concatArrays: ["$$value.id", "$$this"]]}},
              {id: "$$value.id", arr: {$concatArrays: ["$$value.arr", ["$$this"]]}}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {key: 1, id: "$res.id"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RI4MOQZFzvI)

Since **mongoDB version 5.2** we can use `$sortArray`, which I'm not sure if will be faster:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {$project: {
      cleanArr: {$sortArray: {
          input: {$reduce: {
              input: "$a",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.p.id"]}
          }},
          sortBy: 1
      }},
      key: 1,
      _id: 0
  }},
  {$project: {
      key: 1,
      id: {$reduce: {
          input: {$range: [0, {$subtract: [{$size: "$cleanArr"}, 1]}]},
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: [
                      {$arrayElemAt: ["$cleanArr", "$$this"]},
                      {$arrayElemAt: ["$cleanArr", {$add: ["$$this", 1]}]}
                  ]},
                  [{$arrayElemAt: ["$cleanArr", "$$this"]}],
                  []
              ]}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {"id.0": {$exists: true}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FmVyyWjDAwm)

Comment: Thanks @nimrod serok ! The first seems to do the job ! ( actual deployment is version 4.4 )