# faster way to match documents with duplicated fields in nested array of objects across entire collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am searching the faster option to match documents with duplicated values in fields inside nested array , example document matching the criteria:

```
  {
   "key": 1,
   a: [ 
       { p: [ { id: 2 },{ id: 3 }  ] }
     ]
  } ,
  {
   "key": 2,
   a: [ 
       { p: [ { id: 4 },{ id: 3 }  ] }
     ]
  }
```

I need to find faster way to match only the documents having duplicated a.p.id values , in the example documents with key:1 and key:2  have duplicated a.p.id:3  , is this possible without using $uwind and what is the best option , collection is having > 100M documents and it seems double $unwind takes some time(alot of time) ?

mongodb 4.4 , preferred solution -> mongosh/mongo aggregation framework

Expected output:

```
{ id:3 , key:[1,2] }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZrjkmH8RcwD)

Comment: How many id values? How many duplicates?

Comment: Are the ids consecutive m->n?

Comment: no , id's are random strings , not consecustive at all , 5-50 id's per document in 100M total

Comment: What's the difference between this and [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76149670/faster-way-to-identify-documents-with-duplicated-fields-in-nestedt-array-of-obje)?

Comment: The difference is that here we search duplicates per collection and in previous we search duplicates per document ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option is to use `$lookup` with pipeline. I'm not sure it will be faster, but you can run it on batches without affecting the results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      cleanArr: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$a",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.p.id"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      key: 1,
      _id: 0
  }},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        currentKey: "$key",
        cleanArr: "$cleanArr"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $size: {
                    $setIntersection: [
                      {
                        $reduce: {
                          input: "$a",
                          initialValue: [],
                          in: {
                            $concatArrays: [
                              "$$value",
                              "$$this.p.id"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "$$cleanArr"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                "$key",
                "$$currentKey"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            key: 1,
            res: {
              $setIntersection: [
                {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$a",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                      $concatArrays: [
                        "$$value",
                        "$$this.p.id"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                "$$cleanArr"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matching"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "matching.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      result: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$matching",
          initialValue: {
            id: [],
            key: [
              "$key"
            ]
          },
          in: {
            id: {
              $setUnion: [
                "$$value.id",
                "$$this.res"
              ]
            },
            key: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.key",
                [
                  "$$this.key"
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$result.id"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$result.id",
      key: {
        $first: "$result.key"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NRvzAWq5n69)

Comment: not yet tested in the real collection and not sure how it will perform with lookup , but idea seems interesting so I accept it as answer! Thanks!

Comment: There is an option to index array items. It is not always recommended, but may fit your case, even temporarily...